# Laravel 5.7 route Controller with a view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

estoy aprendiendo a usar Laravel 5.7
Tengo el siguiente problema:
Cree un modelo llamado Product cuando intento enviar la información desde ProductController al index, el index parece no recibirla.

**ProductController.php**

```
  <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\Products;


class ProductController extends Controller{
  public function index(){
    $products = Products::paginate(3);
    return view('index', compact('products'));
  }
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      @foreach ($products as $product)
        <tr>
          <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
  (!! $products->render() !!)
</div>
```

***Error***

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Undefined variable: products (View:
>   D:\laravel\imperio\resources\views\index.blade.php) Previous
>   exceptions Undefined variable: products (0)

Comment: la paginación hasta donde se es de este modo `{{ $products->links() }}`

Comment: Es muy raro, aún si no tuvieras productos, no debería aparecer como indefinida la variable. Limpia los caché de la aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ver si realmente tienes productos, bien en el controlador:

```
public function index(){
    $products = Products::paginate(3);
    dump($products);

    return view('index', compact('products'));
}
```

o bien en la vista:

```
<tbody>
    {{ dump($products) }}
    @foreach ($products as $product)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

La función `dump()` funciona de forma similar a `dd()` pero no detiene la ejecución.

Ahora bien, suponiendo que tu código funcionará, podrías tener productos o no tenerlos, debes controlar eso para que la aplicación no falle, por ejemplo:

```
<tbody>
    @if ($products)
        @foreach ($products as $product)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</tbody>
```

La siguiente línea la verdad que no se que hace (creo que es un error de sintaxis):

```
(!! $products->render() !!)
```

Saludos.

Comment: pero si no tuviera registros en dicha tabla, al momento de tratar de mostrarlos en la consulta debería simplemente dejarlo en blanco

Comment: @element eso lo consigues con el bloque `@if`, no se imprime nada el interior cuando *NO hay productos*. Este bloque podría incluir toda la tabla. Alternativamente puedes añadir un `@else` al condicional para indicar que no hay productos disponibles.